# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed while trying to add timestamp to a dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

i have been trying to add timestamp/currentdate to my dataframe using this function

```
val myDF = dataframe.toDF()
        import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{ col, lit, when }
        val currDate = new java.util.Date()
        myDF.withColumn("CreatedAt", lit(new java.sql.Date(currDate.getDate)))
```

But after compilation , the spark-submit job fails with the below exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   requirement failed
>           at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:221)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnresolvedStar.expand(unresolved.scala:199)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$anonfun$apply$10$$anonfun$applyOrElse$14.apply(Analyzer.scala:354)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$anonfun$apply$10$$anonfun$applyOrElse$14.apply(Analyzer.scala:353)
>           at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
>           at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
>           at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
>           at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
>           at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:251)
>           at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:105)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$anonfun$apply$10.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:353)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$anonfun$apply$10.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:347)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$resolveOperators$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:57)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$resolveOperators$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:57)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:69)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperators(LogicalPlan.scala:56)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$.apply(Analyzer.scala:347)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$.apply(Analyzer.scala:328)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:83)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:80)
>           at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:111)
>           at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:84)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:80)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:72)
>           at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.execute(RuleExecutor.scala:72)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:36)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:36)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:34)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.(DataFrame.scala:133)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$withPlan(DataFrame.scala:2126)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.select(DataFrame.scala:707)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.withColumn(DataFrame.scala:1188)
>           at App_Event_1173$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App_Event_1173.scala:71)
>           at App_Event_1173$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App_Event_1173.scala:61)
>           at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:661)
>           at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:661)
>           at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
>           at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
>           at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
>           at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:426)
>           at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:49)
>           at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:49)
>           at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:49)
>           at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
>           at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:39)
>           at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobScheduler.scala:224)
>           at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:224)
>           at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:224)
>           at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
>           at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:223)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

I'm having java version 1.7, spark 1.6.1, scala 2.10.5.Where am i doing this wrong.

Tried with 
`myDF.withColumn("CreatedAt", lit(current_date))` as well.
Nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code with `java 8`, `scala 2.11.8` and `spark 2.1.0`. Your code runs flawlessly.
So I would like you to do the followings:
1. confirm that you are using exactly the **same version of scala and java that your spark is compiled with**. You can simply get this information when you do `spark-shell`.
2. @Vidya is right to say that **you need to get rid of java 7 as spark prefers java 8**. so even if you solve this problem you will get other errors in the future. 
And by the way, try to use the latest releases of `spark` and use `scala` and `java` that the spark you downloaded is compiled with.

Following is what I did :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark Count"))
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

    import sqlContext.implicits._
    val df = Seq(("David", 25, ""), ("Jean", 20, "")).toDF("Name", "age", "uid")

    val myDF = df.toDF()
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{lit}
    val currDate = new java.util.Date()
    myDF.withColumn("CreatedAt", lit(new java.sql.Date(currDate.getDate))).show
  }
}
```